# When using urllib2 HTTPBasicAuthHandler issues with the fact the username contains spaces

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to access a remote URL. Unfortunately the internet at the workplace requires a http proxy with authentication. The username needed for the http proxy authentication contains spaces (don't ask me why).

My code is:

```
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, 'dmn\user x01', 'password')
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

When I try to open a page the following error occurs (I suspect is related to the fact that the username contians spaces):

```
  File "<string>", line 4
    if not x01:password"@proxy.xxx.net:80 ==  : 
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Any suggestions ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It kind of looks like it's sending it as a url, I wonder if escaping the space would work. So that it ends up as: **dmn\user%20x01:password"@proxy.xxx.net:80**. Just a suggestion.